# FORCE_NOT_NULL" LINE 1: ...r_name ) FROM STDIN CSV QUOTE '"' ESCAPE '''' FORCE_NOT_

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to import a table to postgresql database.
Some fields in the csv file has null value as "\N" or "N".
and I am getting this error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FORCE_NOT_NULL"
LINE 1: ...r_name ) FROM STDIN   CSV   QUOTE '"' ESCAPE '''' FORCE_NOT_...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect. It should be

```
COPY ... FROM ... (FORMAT 'csv', QUOTE '"', ESCAPE '''', FORCE_NOT_NULL (...))
```